# is this the correct place to ask educational/review questions?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Any good resources on oracle PL/SQL for review or study?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425920/any-good-resources-on-oracle-pl-sql-for-review-or-study)

I recently posted a question here about educational resources, is Software Engineering the correct place for it? I thought about asking on stack overflow but this seemed to be the better place for it. if not, where should I bring this question?

Answer (score 4):

No, Software Engineering is not a suitable place.

- Advice regarding career or education are usually very personal and can't be answered well with the Stack Exchange question & answer model. See also: [Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Career or Educational Advice?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)
- We're not a good place for getting recommendations for books or resources. Any answers would be based in opinion, which is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model. Furthermore, recommendations don't tend to age well. While you have asked about a rather *stable* technology, tech generally has very short cycles. Learning material might already be outdated within a few years. This conflicts with the goal to build a library of questions and answers that helps other people, not just the person asking the question. See also: [Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Requests for Recommendations?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/)

These reasons are not specific to the Software Engineering site but are largely based on the Stack Exchange model that values long-lasting, objective answers. The same reasons would apply when asking on Stack Overflow. Instead, you might be able to find another site or community that welcomes such questions. For example, recommendations for current learning resources might be on topic in a community or forum specifically about PL/SQL. Reddit is usually a good place for this kind of question, though it's [r/PLSQL](https://www.reddit.com/r/plsql/) community seems rather deserted, unfortunately.

Comment: Oracle provides such a Forum: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/sql_and_pl_sql    - don't how long this link will be valid, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the best place for this kind of question. In fact, resource and reference requests [are specifically off-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'm not aware of any good Stack Exchange site to ask these types of questions. The questions best asked here are questions that require human thought, knowledge, and experience. Finding resources or references to read is something that a search engine is very good at.